# How can I convert the following matlab code into python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab

I have this loop generating a Vandermonde matrix in Matlab, but I want to translate this into Python code. I would like to convert the matlab code to python or someone knows how to run the matlab code in python then it also be very helpful.

```matlab
m = 100; 
n = 15; 
t = (0:m-1)'/(m-1); 
A = []; 

for i = 1:n
     A  = [A  t.^(i-1)]; 
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I understand how to create the t in python using for-loop. But, I am not sure how to implement correctly the form of A into python.

Comment: Show us the Python code you already have!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. The beginning of the code looks very much like Matlab. Just use `numpy.arrange(start, end, step_size)` to define `t`. Don't forget to divide by `m-1` like in your Matlab code.

```
import numpy as np
m = 100;
n = 15;
t = np.arange(0, m, 1)/(m-1)
```

But you need to reshape `t` as follows:

```
t = t.reshape(m,1)
```

`t` is now `m`-by-1.

```
print(t.shape)
```

Initialize your `A` matrix for the first element:

```
A = np.power(t,0);
```

Then run through the `for` loop:

```
for i in range(2,n+1):
    A = np.concatenate((A, np.power(t,i-1)), axis=1)
```

`A` is now `m`-by-`n` and the results match those of Matlab.

```
print(A)
print(A.shape)
```

Let me know if you have any questions. I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Also something to keep in mind if you plan on using much higher dimensions: `np.concatenate` is much more efficient than doing `A = [A, ...]` in a for loop in Matlab. It probably doesn't matter for what you're doing now, but something to think about.